# Pokemon shiny hunting

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Has shinys been more likely to find it pokemon X and Y because I saw it was 2x more likely to find. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it has.**

In Generation VI (X + Y) there are some changes to shiny rates. Yes, shinies occure a little bit more often, Masuda method strikes back and so on. Here is a little excerpt with link:

> **Generation VI**
>
> This generation slightly changed how Shiny Pokémon are determined.
>   While the basic formula is still identical to Generation III and all
>   games since then, the value the formula returns now only has to be
>   less than 16 to result in a Shiny, rather than less than 8. This
>   results in a probability of 16/65536 or 1/4096, double the previous
>   probability.
>
> The Poké Radar returns in this generation after a generation of
>   absence, and the Masuda method and Shiny Charm return as well. A new
>   mechanic to increase the Shiny rate, consecutive fishing, was
>   introduced. The exact rates at which the previous four techniques
>   increase the Shiny probability are currently unknown.

[Shiny article on Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny#Generation_VI)